# HTACCESS Redirects instead of rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, laravel-5.3

Hi i want to redirect www.domain.com/folder/* to www.domain.com/folder/public/*
using apache .htaccess (Apache v 2.2.27)

I have written following but it redirects instead or rewrite (Here it redirects correctly, like www.domain.com/folder/login show the page www.domain.com/folder/public/login)

.htaccess file placed under **folder** folder is below

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/public/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

If i remove flag R=301 and just keep L there,
then the URL www.domain.com/folder searches for this www.domain.com/folder/public/**folder**, I don't know why?

I'm Using this as the root .htaccess file for my laravel 5.3 Project to remove the public folder, But i think the .htaccess file inside the public folder is giving this conflict.

.htaccess file inside the **public** folder is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /folder/public/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

What is that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule inside `/folder/.htaccess`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .php

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]
```

Also **remove rule** under this comment `# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...` from `folder/public/.htaccess` as you don't to expose `public/` in your URLs.

Comment: Thanks for posting. This gives Route not found (404). Probably because when we say www.domain.com/folder it looks for www.domain.com/folder/public/folder which is incorrect (I don't know why), But this should look for www.domain.com/folder/public.

Comment: still same issue. :( Not getting why its searching the current url path in the public folder itself.

Comment: Well i cannot share url here (It's on the live setup). But when i call /folder then it loads the route for /public/folder or when we call /folder/login it calls /public/folder/login

Comment: Yeah, on the browser when i hit "http://example.com/app" then it shows the result of "http://example.com/app/public/app" url (i am not getting why its appending the url paths to the public there)

Comment: yes app is the folder which is the root of the laravel project (Directory inside public_html of my webhost), `http://example.com/app/foobar` shows the result for `http://example.com/app/public/app/foobar`

Comment: No url remains same

Comment: ok then how do you know it is loading `http://example.com/app/public/app/foobar` internally? Also check your `Route` directives for Laravel.

Comment: Because i had doubt as it shows not found page of laravel so i created a route with the folder name and it was loaded there.
Also i have created a subdomain for the project that points to the public folder, there it works.